Need to get the docker image tag of the loaded image from file
I have multiple images with the same name and I have built a script that lets me load an image from the tar and then get it's tag and update the yaml file as well. The issue is, this only works if the image is the latest image in that name.
docker images "$image_name" --format "{{.Tag}}" | sort -rV | head -n 1

Sometimes I need to load an older image which could be older than the latest image. When in this situation I want to get the specific image I load.
eg: If i already have an image gui:test_v1.5 image but I need to load an older image from a tar such as,
docker load -i test_v1.0.tar 

After loading the above image, if i run the
docker images "$image_name" --format "{{.Tag}}" | sort -rV | head -n 1

I still only get the tag for test_v1.5 because according to creation date. I know that the -rV tag is used to sortbased on revision tags.
I can't seem to get the tag of this image. Any possible ways to do that?
I need the tag name so that I can auto update the yaml file using sed in my shell script.

Can you grab the tag from the output of docker load?

i thought about that, but unfortunately it doesn't output the tag when loading the image.

Really? The docs show it as outputting the tag of the loaded image. A quick test I did also outputs the tag when loading the image.

Yes my bad. I Just tested it out. It worked! Thanks a lot!

Do you control the image tags and the filename?  If so, can you extract the tag from the filename, or use the same parameter to generate the filename and the tags?  Can you run a Docker registry instead of copying around image tar files?

I don't have much control over the file names in all instances, hence why I wanted a more robust solution.
Therefore i decided to save the output of docker load and then get the image tag from that.
load_output=$(docker load -i "$Image_TAR_FILE")
loaded_image=$(echo "$load_output" | awk '/Loaded image:/ {print $3}')

You can extract the data from the tar file. The repositories or manifests.json files will have the content you are looking for. E.g.
tar -xf test_v1.0.tar --to-stdout repositories \
  | jq -r ".[\"${repository}\"] | keys | .[0]"

